# Create a Form in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, asp.net, custom-form

I want to make a form in Sharepoint Online without using Infopath. But I am having a hard time finding other option. There are things that I am considering;

1. List - but list columns has no Rich Text Format and I need it in my form.
2. ASP.Net Web Forms - I have a difficulty finding a right step by step tutorial in making a form in Sharepoint using ASP.net.

Please help. I am just a newbie in sharepoint. :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you arrive at the assumption in point 1.? List forms ***do*** have rich text and enhanced rich text and support them in SharePoint native forms. If you don't want to use InfoPath, you can create forms in SharePoint Designer.

As a general tip: Don't customize the out of the box forms. Instead create a new form for "New", "Display", "Edit" and style the Data Form Web Part that gets created automatically.

Comment: @teylyn.. My Bad.. I have found the option in making a rich text column in my list.. Thanks for the quick reply..

I am now confused in making a form in sharepoint because I cant design my form.. The design tab is disabled.. Is it okay?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Which Design tab? Open the site in SharePoint Designer, navigate to the list and in the List Settings page, in the Forms panel, click to create a new form. You will need to select either "new", "display" or "edit". Then SPD shows a Data Form Web part. It is arranged in an HTML table. You can move elements around and style them to your liking.

Comment: I am making use of Sharepoint Designer 2013.. When I open the newly added aspx form page in SPD, I can see html codes. So, there is no design tab, for me to control the UI of my form?

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2013 does not have a Design view. You will need to use code view to work with the web part. But a Data Form Web Part is just an HTML table with XSL inside the cells. You will need to learn XSL basics to control what shows in the cells, but to re-arrange and style the form you just need to re-arrange and style the HTML. Save often. Preview in the browser.

Comment: Okay @teylyn. Now I know. At least i wont be confused. thanks for always helping me. :))